# how to display legend on right side of piechart in achartengine android

Tags: android, android-layout, achartengine

I am using the pie chart view from achartengine's tutorial. Here is what i want.

[image]

I want the legends i.e. pass/fail to be displayed to the right of the pie chart as shown in the figure. In the demo examples of achartengine, they are bottom aligned. How to get them to the right? Please help!

Comment: I added a transparent frameLayout on top of it, and got what i achieved.

Comment: How did you do that? Can you be more specific?some sample code??

Comment: If you want post your solution in my question in order to have it in StackOverflow.Many users may want it...

Comment: @ Shafi could please post a sample code for where to add the frame layout.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to the code right now. But from what I remember, I did the following:
In the layout file, add a framelayout, make it transparent (our piechart will be behind this layout) and add the legends to this layout via code. Add the piechart as a view(not as intent). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This code below worked for me. But I think it's better creating a RecyclerView as a legend, instead of using the one provided by MPAndroidChart class.
What I did:

1. Create the *RecyclerView* and *celda_recycler_legend.xml*:
2. Create an *AdapterLegend.java* script, which extents *RecyclerView.Adapter class*, to be able to use a RecyclerView with the legends. On this script, I added a *LegendViewHolder* instance, which extents *RecyclerView.ViewHolder*, with the *celda_recycler_legend.xml* configured.

*AdapterLegend*

```
 class AdapterLegend extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private ArrayList<String> legends;
    private ArrayList<Integer> colors;

    public AdapterLegend(ArrayList legends, ArrayList<Integer> colors) {
        this.legends = legends;
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new LegendViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.celda_recycler_legend, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LegendViewHolder legendViewHolder = (LegendViewHolder) holder;
        legendViewHolder.LoadLegend(legends.get(position), colors.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return legends.size(); }
  }
```

*LegendViewHolder*

```
class LegendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView legendText;
    private final ImageView legendColorLabel;

    public LegendViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        legendText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.legendTextView);
        legendColorLabel = itemView.findViewById(R.id.legendLabelColor);
    }

    public void LoadLegend(String legend, int legendColor){
        legendText.setText(legend);
        legendColorLabel.setBackgroundColor(legendColor);
    }
}
```

3. I set the *RecyclerView* with an *AdapterLegend* instance

   ```
      legendRecyclerView = recountDataLayout.findViewById(R.id.chartLegendRecycler);
      legendRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
   ```

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2478#issuecomment-378566623

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hello @Mansi I didn't know that. Now I'm going to correct my answer thanks!